# Thunderbird version of Outlook's Conversation Cleanup (remove earlier msgs in thread)?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

Outlook has a "Conversation Clean Up" function that deletes redundant emails in a thread, keeping only the last message that contains the text of earlier ones -- in other words, contains the whole conversation up to that point. See:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Conversation-Clean-Up-to-eliminate-redundant-messages-4a0aa10b-8342-4f75-b78c-2b8ca23eca8d

Is there a way to do that in Thunderbird?